# Esqueletización de una imagen. ¿Cómo quitar pixeles y completar lineas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagen, opencv

Cuando aplico esqueletización de una imagen en algunas partes las lineas son muy gruesas o se separan. No se si falta aplicar un filtro más o los parámetros deben ser diferentes.

Hice varias pruebas con el umbral y es lo mejor que he podido obtener:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('img.png',0)
size = np.size(img)
skel = np.zeros(img.shape,np.uint8)

ret,img = cv2.threshold(img,172,255,0)
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
done = False

while( not done):
    eroded = cv2.erode(img,element)
    temp = cv2.dilate(eroded,element)
    temp = cv2.subtract(img,temp)
    skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skel,temp)
    img = eroded.copy()

    zeros = size - cv2.countNonZero(img)
    if zeros==size:
        done = True

cv2.imshow("skel",skel)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Imagen original

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

resultado de el codigo ala derecha se ve en algunas parte son gruesas y otra se separa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En su día tuve un problema similar con un algoritmo de reconocimiento de caracteres, principalmente en el cruce de lineas. Una buena alternativa puede ser aplicar el algoritmo que expone @HYRY en su [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15136318/7131499) a una pregunta similar en el sitio en inglés, usando la transformación de localización mediante[`scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_hit_or_miss`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_hit_or_miss.html).

Este es el mismo algoritmo con algunas modificaciones, por ejemplo para evitar el uso de listas y algunas operaciones intermedias realmente no necesarias:

```
import scipy.ndimage.morphology as morp
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def skeletonize(img):

    struct =  np.array([
        [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]],
         [[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]],

        [[[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]],
         [[0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]]],

        [[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1]],
         [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]],

        [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]],
         [[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]],

        [[[1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
         [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]],

        [[[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]],
         [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0]]],

        [[[1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0]],
         [[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1]]],

        [[[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
         [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]]]]
        )


    img = img.copy()
    last = ()
    while np.any(img != last):
        last = img
        for s in struct:
            img = np.logical_and(img, np.logical_not(morp.binary_hit_or_miss(img, *s)))
    return img


img = cv2.imread("/home/fjsevilla/Escritorio/lZXDg.png", 0)
ret, img = cv2.threshold(img, 176, 255, 0)
skel = skeletonize(img)

# Para ver el resultado en matplotlib aplicando además interpolación
plt.imshow(skel, cmap="gray", interpolation="nearest")
plt.show()
```

Para tu ejemplo obtenemos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

### Edición 13/08/2019

En versiones recientes de NumPy el código anterior lanza una alerta:

> ```
> DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed;
>       this will raise an error in the future.
>   while np.any(img != last):
> ```

El problema es que inicialmente `last` es una tupla vacía y por tanto con diferentes dimensiones que `img`. Esto no era un problema en versiones antiguas de NumPy pero si ahora y en el futuro ocasionará una excepción. La solución es simplemente hacer que `last` tenga las mismas dimensiones que `img` antes de iniciar el ciclo:

```
img = img.copy()
last = np.empty_like(img)       # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
while np.any(img != last):
    last = img
    for s in struct:
        img = np.logical_and(img, np.logical_not(morp.binary_hit_or_miss(img, *s)))
return img
```

Comment: funciona muy bien la libreria que usaste

Comment: hice algunas pruebas y si consegui la imagen mas limpia ,gracias